# Nuxt:Vuex update data from button click not working. error "Cannot read property 'results' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, vuex

I've using the store to update data in a pages file. The really strange thing is the data sometimes appears if i add/remove "results" from `state.mbbalance.results`
If I add .results I get an error.

`Cannot read property 'results' of undefined`

If I remove the .results and leave as `state.mbbalance` ,click the button
I can see the data networks tab in browser as a valid response. But the data won't display on webpage.

`results: [{id: 7, balance: 30, exposure: 0, free_funds: 30},…]`

I'm not sure why I get the error as the code should work as expected and display a list of balances from the backend. Can anyone tell me why the data won't update?

versions

```json
"nuxt": "2.15.7",
"@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
```

This is my store.

**store/index.js**

```js
export default {
  state: () => ({
    loggedIn: false,
    user: null
  }),
  actions: {
    async nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req, app }) {
      console.log('nuxtServerInit', req.session.authToken)
      if (req.session.authToken) {
        const data = await app.$axios.$get('/api/auth/me/')
        commit('SET_USER', data)
      } else {
        commit('SET_USER', null)
      }
    },
    async login ({ commit }, creds) {
      await this.$axios.$post('/auth/login/', creds)
      const data = await this.$axios.$get('/api/auth/me/')
      commit('SET_USER', data)
    },
    logout ({ commit }) {
      this.$axios.$post('/auth/logout/')
      commit('SET_USER', null)
    },
    async getMBalance(context) {
      const res = await this.$axios.get('api/balance/')
      if (!res.error) {
          context.commit("SET_MB_BALANCE", res.data)
      } else {
          context.commit("SET_MB_BALANCE", [])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**pages/balance.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="updateItem">get</button>
    <table>
        <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
      <th>Balance</th>
      </tr>
        </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr v-for="o in mbbaldata" :key="o.id">
              <td>{{o.balance}}</td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapMutations, mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    mbbaldata: (state) => state.mbbalance.results,
  })
},
methods: {
  updateItem() {
    this.mb_balance = this.$store.dispatch('getMBalance')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: add the relevant mutation to the question. also, you are referencing an inexistent state property: `mbbalance`.

Comment: Also, a [repro] could be useful here.